# Python textbox program

Tags: python, textbox, alias, reply

I want to write a Python program that will be able to read from a dictionary into any (or most) textboxes.   Will this be possible and how would I approach it?

Here is an example of what I mean with the first line being an example of a command I'd like to be able type to receive the 2nd line which would be the message stored in the dictionary value:

```
/alias hello 
HELLO!  THIS IS AN AUTOMATED REPLY!  :D
```

Comment: What textboxes are your referring to? Where are you hoping to type that command? Chances are what you want can be done with AutoHotkey http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: This is definitely possible, let me say that first.

Comment: Auto-hokey is close to what I want, but I want to do it in Python myself.  Not sure where to start though.

Answer (score 0):

Store the dictionary as key,value pair in the form {key:value}. In the key part write your commands like 'hello' and in the value part give your corresponding message like ' HELLO!  THIS IS AN AUTOMATED REPLY!  :D'. You can access your value from its key. For eg:

```
   abc = {"hello" : "HELLO!  THIS IS AN AUTOMATED REPLY!  :D"}

   print abc["hello"]
```

It will print "HELLO!  THIS IS AN AUTOMATED REPLY!  :D".

I think this is what you meant. Actually I haven't understood what you meant by textboxes..

Comment: I know how to do this part, I don't think you understand that I want the keyvalue printed to like any text box that I happen to be at.

Comment: I think that would be related to some GUI programming.